# QtConcurrent: why releaseThread and reserveThread cause deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtconcurrent

In Qt 4.7 Reference for `QThreadPool`, we find:

> ### `void QThreadPool::releaseThread()`
>
> Releases a thread previously reserved by a call to `reserveThread()`.
>
> Note: Calling this function without previously reserving a thread
>   temporarily increases `maxThreadCount()`. **This is useful when a thread
>   goes to sleep waiting for more work, allowing other threads to
>   continue. Be sure to call `reserveThread()` when done waiting, so that
>   the thread pool can correctly maintain the `activeThreadCount()`**.
>
> See also `reserveThread()`.
>
> ---
>
> ### `void QThreadPool::reserveThread()`
>
> Reserves one thread, disregarding `activeThreadCount()` and
>   `maxThreadCount()`.
>
> Once you are done with the thread, call `releaseThread()` to allow it to
>   be reused.
>
> Note: This function will always increase the number of active threads.
>   This means that by using this function, it is possible for
>   `activeThreadCount()` to return a value greater than `maxThreadCount()`.
>
> See also `releaseThread()`.

I want to use `releaseThread()` to make it possible to use nested concurrent map, but in the following code, it hangs in `waitForFinished()`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtConcurrentMap>
#include <QtConcurrentRun>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QtTest/QTest>
#include <QFutureSynchronizer>

struct Task2 { // only calculation
    typedef void result_type;
    void operator()(int count) {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count * 10; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < count * 10; ++j) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        assert(k >= 0);
    }
};

struct Task1 { // will launch some other concurrent map
    typedef void result_type;
    void operator()(int count) {

        QVector<int> vec;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            vec.push_back(i+count);
        }
        Task2 task;

        QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::map(vec.begin(), vec.end(), task);
        {
            // with out releaseThread before wait, it will hang directly
            QThreadPool::globalInstance()->releaseThread();
            f.waitForFinished(); // BUG: may hang there
            QThreadPool::globalInstance()->reserveThread();
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    QThreadPool* gtpool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    gtpool->setExpiryTimeout(50);
    int count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        QVector<int> vec;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40 ; i++) {
            vec.push_back(i);
        }
        // launch a task with nested map
        Task1 task; // Task1 will have nested concurrent map
        QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::map(vec.begin(), vec.end(),task);

        f.waitForFinished(); // BUG: may hang there

        count++;

        // waiting most of thread in thread pool expire
        while (QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount() > 0) {
            QTest::qSleep(50);
        }

        // launch a task only calculation
        Task2 task2;
        QFuture<void> f2 = QtConcurrent::map(vec.begin(), vec.end(), task2);

        f2.waitForFinished(); // BUG: may hang there

        qDebug() << count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code will not run forever; it will hang in after many loops (1~10000), with all threads waiting for condition variable.

My questions are:

1. Why does it hang?
2. Can I fix it and keep the nested concurrent map?

dev env:

Linux version 2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64; Qt4.7.4; GCC 3.4.5

Windows 7; Qt4.7.4; mingw 4.4.0

Comment: Your program runs smoothly on linux, so if it hangs in windows, there are differences in concurrent implementations.

Comment: @tunglt it hangs both windows and linux, I have update to env info, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program hangs because of the race condition in QThreadPool when you try to deal with expiryTimeout. Here is the analysis in detail :

**The problem in QThreadPool** - [source](https://woboq.com/blog/qwaitcondition-solving-unavoidable-race.html)

> When starting a task, QThreadPool did something along the lines of:

```
QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

taskQueue.append(task); // Place the task on the task queue
if (waitingThreads > 0) {
   // there are already running idle thread. They are waiting on the 'runnableReady' 
   // QWaitCondition. Wake one up them up.
   waitingThreads--;
   runnableReady.wakeOne();
} else if (runningThreadCount < maxThreadCount) {
   startNewThread(task);
}
```

> And the the thread's main loop looks like this:

```
void QThreadPoolThread::run()
{
  QMutexLocker locker(&manager->mutex);
  while (true) {
    /* ... */
    if (manager->taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
      // no pending task, wait for one.
      bool expired = !manager->runnableReady.wait(locker.mutex(), 
                                                  manager->expiryTimeout);
      if (expired) {
        manager->runningThreadCount--;
        return;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    QRunnable *r = manager->taskQueue.takeFirst();
    // run the task
    locker.unlock();
    r->run();
    locker.relock();
  }
}
```

> The idea is that the thread will wait for a given amount of second for
>   a task, but if no task was added in a given amount of time, the thread
>   expires and is terminated. The problem here is that we rely on the
>   return value of runnableReady. **If there is a task that is scheduled at
>   exactly the same time as the thread expires, then the thread will see
>   false and will expire. But the main thread will not restart any other
>   thread. That might let the application hang as the task will never be
>   run.**

The quick workaround is to use a long expiryTime (30000 by default) and remove the while loop that waits for the threads expired.

Here is the main function modified, the program runs smoothly in Windows 7, 4 threads used by default :

```
int main() {
    QThreadPool* gtpool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    //gtpool->setExpiryTimeout(50); <-- don't set the expiry Timeout, use the default one.
    qDebug() << gtpool->maxThreadCount();

    int count = 0;
    for (;;) {

        QVector<int> vec;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40 ; i++) {
            vec.push_back(i);
        }
        // launch a task with nested map
        Task1 task; // Task1 will have nested concurrent map
        QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::map(vec.begin(), vec.end(),task);

        f.waitForFinished(); // BUG: may hang there

        count++;

        /*
        // waiting most of thread in thread pool expire
        while (QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount() > 0)
        {
            QTest::qSleep(50);
        }
        */

        // launch a task only calculation
        Task2 task2;
        QFuture<void> f2 = QtConcurrent::map(vec.begin(), vec.end(), task2);

        f2.waitForFinished(); // BUG: may hang there

        qDebug() << count ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@tungIt's answer is good enough, I found the qtbug and fix commit, just for reference:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3786

https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/a9b6a78e54670a70b96c122b10ad7bd64d166514#diff-6d5794cef91df41c39b5e7cc6b71d041